# How to autowire an object passing application properties with Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a class like this:

```
@Component
public class KafkaConsumer {

    ...

    @KafkaListener(id = "${my-id}", topics = "${my-topics}")
    public void receive(String myMessage) {
        ...
    }
...
}
```

and I want to reuse it as it is but changing `id` and `topics` params. These params should come from the `application.yml`, in this way:

```
consumer1:
   id: id1
   topics: topic1

consumer2:
   id: id2
   topics: topic2
```

and from another service doing something like:

```
@Service
class MyService {

   
   @Autowired(my-id="{consumer1.id}", my-topics="{consumer1.topics}")
   KafkaConsumer consumer1;

   @Autowired(my-id="{consumer2.id}", my-topics="{consumer2.topics}")
   KafkaConsumer consumer2;

...

}
```

what is the closest way to do that?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/index.html

Comment: I went through the doc but I could not find it. Please can you point me at that?